# Php Array Convertion in different format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

Here I'am using php array concept,I have a array in php just like $array=array('name1,name2');I want to convert this array into following format for some requirement $array=('name1','name2');

And please let me know,how to convert first array into second array format and also what is the difference between this two array format.
    Please help me...

This is what I have done so far

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row) { 
    $galleries[]= $row["subjects"]; 
    $ids = join("','",$galleries); 
} 
echo $pps="SELECT * FROM student_register 
                    WHERE s_name IN ('$ids')";
```

I got output like this :

```
SELECT * FROM student_register 
         WHERE s_name IN ('english,malayalam,hindi')
```

Instead of above I want following output

```
SELECT * FROM student_register 
         WHERE s_name IN ('english','malayalam','hindi')
```

Comment: Well the second format isn't valid PHP for one thing

Comment: Did you mean $array=['name1','name2'] ? [] is an array in PHP.

Comment: My code is looking like,
   foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
     {
         $galleries[]= $row["subjects"];
         $ids = join("','",$galleries);
     }
              
     echo $pps="SELECT * FROM student_register WHERE s_name IN ('$ids')";
I got output 
      SELECT * FROM student_register WHERE s_name IN ('english,malayalam,hindi') Instead of aboue i want following output
   SELECT * FROM student_register WHERE s_name IN ('english','malayalam','hindi')

Comment: Try `implode()` instead of `join()`

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use CI query builder's `where_in` to get the desired result

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row) 
{ 
    $ids[] = $row["subjects"]; 
} 

$this->db->where_in('s_name', $ids);
$result = $this->db->get('student_register')->result();
//print_r($result);
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Sir please do upvote my answer too thanks n happy  coding